# Trying to search a string for a gets input in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, include, gets

I am having issues searching for a string input by the user using `gets`. Here's the outline:

```
puts "What are we searching for?"
search = gets
z=1
result = []
file = File.open('somefile.txt', 'r+')

file.each do |line| 
  if line.include?(search)
    result << z
  end
  puts line
  z+=1
end

puts "Found on line(s) #{result}
```

The issue seems to be with `if line.include?(search)`. When I replace `(search)` with the value I am searching for--such as `("example01")`-- this script works fine. But when using the value input by the user--using `gets`, it never seems to find it. `("#{search}")` doesn't work either.

I have also tried using regular expressions by swapping

```
if line.include?(search)
```

with

```
if line =~ Regexp.new(search)
```

with the same issue.

What is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
search = gets.chomp
```

Your current implementation also stores the line-return you are adding from the input. The chomp will get rid of the \n or \r.

Comment: This is a very common Ruby gotcha. So common that I don't understand why there isn't a `getstring` that does it automatically...

Comment: Well if that wasn't a ruby litmus test, I don't know what is. Thanks Kassym.